# Add the continuous date period records into one record with sql

Tags: mysql, sql, data-analysis

Original Data:

```
ID  Date        Original_col
A   2021-04-10    1
B   2021-03-01    1
B   2021-05-01    1
C   2021-03-01    1
C   2021-03-02    2
C   2021-03-03    3
C   2021-05-07    1
```

Result data:

```
ID  Date        Result_col
A   2021-04-10    1
B   2021-03-01    1
B   2021-05-01    1
C   2021-03-01    3
C   2021-05-07    1
```

For ID = 'C' records, records with date between '2021-03-01' to '2021-03-03' are grouped together, only start date '2021-03-01' and max day '3' is kept, record with date = '2021-05-07' is kept cause there are no bigger records.

There are no strict restrictions on 'the date period', I need to group them together if they are continuous on Original_col.

Comment: Please add some specifics on what your desired results mean by *"sum the same date period"*. What date period? What summation? Based on the Result data, I can not make a proper association, guessing ID and Year+Month for the date periods of the records. eg: `GROUP BY ID, DATE_FORMAT("%Y%m", Date)`, but a summation would mean `ID, MIN(Date), SUM(Original_col)` would result in `C 2021-03-01 6` and not `C 2021-03-01 3`, maybe `MAX(Original_col)` instead?

Comment: Could even be `SELECT ID, MIN(Date), COUNT(Date) ... GROUP BY ID, YEAR(Date), MONTH(Date)`, where *"sum"* is erroneously used in place of  `count`?

Comment: Note that, by convention, the term 'ID' is normally reserved for a surrogate PRIMARY KEY.

Comment: And are we to understand that if the final row had been '2021-03-04', it would still have been kept ('as there are no bigger records')

Comment: And see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7GmTAusP4oa3tATphXErr9/0

Comment: This one is empty @Strawberry

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: @PcWang you have to click **Run** to execute the statement and see the results of the db-fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

You can identify the periods by subtracting an enumerated value.  This is constant for "adjacent" days.  The rest is just aggregation:

```
select id, min(date), max(original_col) as result_col
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by date) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by id, (date - interval seqnum day);
```

If the `original_column` is really enumerating the adjacent dates, then you don't even need a subquery:

```
select id, min(date), max(original_col) as result_col
from t
group by id, (date - interval original_col day);
```

However, I don't know if the values are just coincidences in the sample data in the question.